# I use SourceTree with Git but need to work with SVN repistory, what options do I have?

Tags: git, svn, atlassian-sourcetree

Some open source projects I am interested in have been tracked using Subversion rather than Git. I know nothing about Subversion. Recenly, I have learnt about Git and SourceTree and am very familiar with these two things.

Now the question is, what options do I have to view the Subversion project history since SourceTree cannot be used for this? I want to be able to clone the repository to view the history and also make changes. I don't think there is a way to convert the subversion information into Git information.

Comment: How does this not meet the guidelines for this forum?
I am Git user and want to access SVN repository and don't know where to start. Where else should I post this on? SuperUser?

Comment: Sorry for the moderation on your question. I suppose said question would be better received if it described what you tried, how it failed and what is missing: a less open-ended question. Still, I have described in my answer below the general idea.

Comment: This site usually shies away from software recommendation questions questions as well. You might try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok, I tried to delete this question but the website does not allow me to do it

Answer (score 4):

If those opensource projects are no longer active in their Subversion referential, you could:

- clone them locally (you can use [TortoiseSVN for example](https://tortoisesvn.net/))
- use [SubGit](https://subgit.com/) to make a one-time conversion between the local SVN repository and a new local Git repository.
- push the new Git repository to a new upstream repository hosting service.

But if the SVN repository is still active, then you would need to use [`git svn`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn), as described in [this article](https://www.preining.info/blog/2018/06/git-and-subversion-collaboration/), in order to do `git svn fetch`/`git svn dcommit`.

Comment: hmm, that is quite a lot of new stuff there hmmm